# How can I move my Dropbox contents to someone else's Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

How do I move the photos in my Dropbox, to another person's Dropbox?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to **Invite Others** for the folder in question. Then, they are welcome to copy, move or edit the files just like normal.

Comment: Oh...ok, thanks. I'm assuming I will see that option somewhere?

Comment: In the web interface you'll see a link like this http://i.imgur.com/tCPt9UB.png which does the sharing/inviting.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to **MOVE** the files from one account (`User1`) to the other person's account (`User2`), and free up the space in your own account do the following:

1. `User1` opens *Shared Folder Options*.

   [image: Screenshot of a folder's context menu]
2. `User1` invites `User2` to share the folder. `User2` must accept the invitation.

   [image]
3. Once User2 accepts, User1 goes back to Shared folder options, clicks on the settings sprocket next to User2's name and makes User2 the owner.

   [image: Screenshot of Shared Folder Options]
4. The folder is now effectively moved to `User2`'s account, and still shared with `User1`.  To fully complete the move operation, `User2` can *Unshare* the folder or *Kick out* `User1` so that the folder is no longer even visible to `User1`.

   [image: Screenshot showing the Kick Out option]

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with a multi-cloud management application, MultCloud is one and free.
adding your two accounts in it then you can move by dragging directly.
https://www.multcloud.com
All the best

Answer (score 0):

I still feel like picture based answers are still the best for some situation so here's it.

- Login to your dropbox account at its website at dropbox's site
- You will see something similar to the picture below(with all of the folder listing, some of my folders are erased for privacy reasons)
- Right click the folder that you wanted to share and click **Share Link**

[image: http://i1352.photobucket.com/albums/q647/wcypierre/webappsstackexchangecom%2039178/webapps39178pic1filtered_zpsfdc457bd.png]

- You will see something similar to the picture below

[image: http://i1352.photobucket.com/albums/q647/wcypierre/webappsstackexchangecom%2039178/webapps39178pic2_zpsf5e8f68a.png]

- You will have two options: Send via email or get the link directly(as per shown in the picture above)
- You can type the email of the recipient and the message that you wanted to give and click **Send** Otherwise, you can click **Get Link** and share it to your friends instead by distributing the link manually